# Android SQLite fts3: What should I insert: null values OR empty strings?

Tags: android, sqlite, null, string, fts3

I've created a SQLite FTS3 table for an Android app with several columns. The table is populated by user's inputs. However not all table columns should have a value. Example: There is a column named PLURAL. The user submits a word which is a verb (not a noun) and so the PLURAL column shouldn't have a value.

What should I input into the PLURAL column, a NULL value or an empty string ""?

Except for the logic that affects the answer, is there any significant difference in the Database performance if I use NULL over empty string values? Are there any known issues (e.g. throw exceptions) if I use NULL values?

I 've searched around the web and I 've found some opinions on other DB but not on SQLite fts3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Based on logic: you should not insert empty string but `NULL`, since in SQL word `NULL` is treated as [NO VALUE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

There's no preformance issues related to emptyness or nulliness of string. The only consideration can emerge in case of SQL `inner join` statement. `INNER JOIN` joins only non `NULL` fields which fits to join conditions. There's special `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` statements which permits usage of `NULL` fields in joins.

Answer (score 1):

what i understood after going through multiple posts is that it handles null as combination of behavior from different database engines.

The goal is to make SQLite handle NULLs in a standards-compliant way. But the descriptions in the SQL standards on how to handle NULLs seem ambiguous. It is not clear from the standards documents exactly how NULLs should be handled in all circumstances.

**refer this for detailed information
http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html**